# Include Zend Mail Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have Zend in the root of my application:

```
myapp/Zend
```

How can I include it in my application? I've tried include_once, require_once and set_include_path but nothing seems to work. I keep receiving the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Mail\Message' not found in
```

I've created a file called 'mail-test.php' and here is the code:

```
use Zend\Mail\Message;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport; 
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;

$message = new Message();
$message->addTo('myfriend@example.com')
        ->addFrom('email@example.com')
        ->setSubject('Contact Form');
$message->setBody('This is my message, read it.');

$transport = new SmtpTransport();
$options   = new SmtpOptions(array(
    'name'              => 'my.secure.server',
    'host'              => '555.555.5.55',
    'port'              => 465, // Notice port change for TLS is 587
    'connection_class'  => 'plain',
    'connection_config' => array(
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'ssl'      => 'tls',
    ),
));
$transport->setOptions($options);
$transport->send($message);
```

Comment: Did you use Composer to install Zend Framework?

Comment: I used http://www.softaculous.com/ to install on my server. Once it was installed there was a "Zend" library in the root of my application.